# String.Split() Function mysteriously ignoring duplicates

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, split

In Unity3D I am reading a textfile with information on nodes and its connections.

However it seems that ALL duplicates are removed automatically!

```
           for (int j = 0; j < tokens.Length; j++)
           {
               Debug.Log(tokens[j]);
           } }
```

Results in console:

```
Node,Node2,Node2,Lamp,Lamp,Node1,Node3,Node4   // string text
Node
Node2
Lamp
Node1
Node3
Node4
```

Thus it seems that it skips duplicates, when looping over the array.

Comment: Just tested and it doesn't remove the duplicates. Can you please share your framework version?

Comment: The split function does not remove duplicates automatically. Can you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: What's a `$string`? Use `string` instead.

Comment: You're certainly screwing it up somewhere else, give us your whole method as well as the full input file, split does not remove anything except empty entries in some cases, certainly not words.

Comment: Did Joe Blow's answer helped you? In this case mark it as answer!

Answer (score 5):

This is an **infamous gotchya in Unity**:

very simply, in the Unity console:

***IT DOES NOT PRINT DUPLICATES!!!***

[image]

Look more carefully by the console output, and there's a `Collapse` toggle that makes it show or not show duplicates.

[image]

It's that simple.

Comment: Already figured I would get this answer as I did read up on the documentation that clearly indicates that split() does not remove duplicates. I edited the question with more information and testresults.

Answer (score -3):

Even though split shouldn't remove duplicates (tested [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CNub0b)) you could try using Regex and Linq.

```
var words = Regex.Matches("Node,Node2,Node2,Lamp,Lamp,Node1,Node3,Node4", @",?(\w+)").Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Groups[1].Value);
```

Comment: If Split isn't working, then the problem clearly lies in code that the OP hasn't shown us. This is very basic string handling, and doesn't need replacing with regular expressions.