# Remove useless data while printing in Unity console

Tags: debugging, unity-game-engine

I'm new in Unity3D.

While I `print()` some values, I always get useless text like 
`UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour:print(Object)` in Console tab.

Is there a way to remove it from console? Or I just have to get used to it?

Comment: also, watch for the COLLAPSE button in Console, it can be helpful

Comment: heh .. http://stackoverflow.com/a/34713627/294884

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Outside of maximizing the console filters (in the upper right of the console window), use a '\n' at the end of your messages, like so.

```
Debug.Log("Here is my error.\n");
```

This will eliminate additional clutter.

Comment: right. it's worth noting if ou click on ONE LINE of the console, then look DOWN, you see "all the other lines" you logged.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you just have to get used to it. I believe you get the same when you use `Debug.Log()` as well.