# Calling switch statements in Awake or Start

Tags: unity-game-engine

Is there something wrong with the following code? The `Debug` prints the right `chosenScenario` but whichever option (1,2,3,4) I test, it never makes it in the `switch` block...
Am I doing something silly?

```
void Awake()
{
    Setup();
}

void Setup()
{
    // Retrieve the user's selected scenario through player preference log.
    string selectedScenario = PlayerPrefs.GetString("selectedScenario");
    int chosenScenario = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("chosenScenario");

    // Print some useful information.
    Debug.Log("Selected Training Scenario is " + selectedScenario + " which is scenario number " + chosenScenario);

    switch (chosenScenario)
    {
        case 1:
                Debug.Log("Made it here 1");
                break;
        case 2:
                Debug.Log("Made it here 2");
                break;
        case 3:
                Debug.Log("Made it here 3");
                break;
        case 4:
                Debug.Log("Made it here 4");
                break;
        default:
                Debug.Log(chosenScenario);
                break;
    }
}
```

A screenshot of the console output:
[image]

Comment: What if chosenScenario is zero?

Comment: if chosenScenario is in 1-4 range, everything looks okay.

Comment: I know it is `4` because in a script (run before this one) I set it to `4` so I expect to see the `Made it here 4` message, but nothing is printed to console...

Comment: The `Debug.Log("Chosen scenario number " + chosenScenario);` prints out `4` but the `4` case does not print out `Made it here 4`

Comment: What happens if you add a `default` branch that prints the `chosenScenario`? And/or another debug line after the `switch`?

Comment: Nothing happens when I add: `default: Debug.Log("default"); break;`

Comment: I would suggest to put some other instruction in case block, like seting text to Text component to see if for sure it is not going to correct case, couse MAYBE you just found bug in Debug.Log.

Comment: Does it works if you move the code into the Start?

Comment: @Max_Power89 No, it doesn't. I tried putting it in `Start()`

Comment: Is there any way you can provide us with a small example project which demonstrates this issue? Ideally stripped of all we don't need.

Comment: That log output (with reference to `4`) is a different log message.

Comment: Fix the null reference error. It is more than likely messing with the rest of your output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this:

```
  switch (chosenScenario)
    {
        case 0:
                Debug.Log("Hell, the preference was not saved");
                break;
        case 1:
                Debug.Log("Made it here 1");
                break;
        .. continue as before ..
```

and you will instantly see your problem.

Regarding this,

> Debug.Log("Chosen scenario number " + chosenScenario);

I want you to actually **take a screen shot of the console**, and show us the output!

---

With weird Console problems like this, there are **four critical points** to remember

1. Carefully check on the console *where the Debug output line comes from*
2. Click on the console line, to see much more information in the "bottom section"
3. Never ever print a naked `Debug.Log(x)`, instead do this `Debug.Log("yo "+x);`
4. And don't forget the **infamous "collapse" gotchya!** https://stackoverflow.com/a/34713627/294884

---

Your problem is likely:

> I know it is 4 because in a script (run before this one) I set it to 4 so I expect to see the Made it here 4 message, but nothing is printed to console

Always, always, always run "Save" after setting prefs (it's just one of those stupid things about Unity)...

```
PlayerPrefs.SetString(PString, fs);
PlayerPrefs.Save();
```

Here's a typical example routine...

```
private void WritePrefs()
    {
    List<string> ff = new List<string>();
    foreach (Thingy th in Thingies ) ff.Add(th.Info.handyCode);
    string fs = String.Join(",", ff.ToArray());
    PlayerPrefs.SetString(PString, fs);
    PlayerPrefs.Save();
    }
```

Comment: I didn't know about `PlayerPrefs.Save();` so I'm gonna try this first! Thank you

Comment: The different msg was just a different debug text. Adding a default branch didn't work. I will start from scratch; i.e. a fresh C# script attached to my game object. I am confused and t's getting messy here, with the huge bold text, etc... Thanks for your attention S.L. Barth

Comment: @Jtech It's not useful posting code and log output that don't match and removing the `default` case.  It's just causing confusion.

Comment: @trojanfoe Sorry, you are right. I was just using different debug messages in different places to see what was the problem. I think I should delete this question anyway. It is causing confusion for everyone. Apologies

Comment: Hi @Jtech - no confusion whatsoever.  This question is a billion times better than 90% of the Unity3D questions on here. It's a good (if simple) question with a good answer, which contains various useful info.  **You'd never delete it after all this work!**  Please "Tick" something to keep the board tidy, and move on!  Now, back to the bar!

Comment: @JoeBlow OK but back to the question; if the OP is getting `4` and there is a `case` covering that, the issue is unresolved and there is no answer to accept.

Comment: @  trojanfoe Exactly. I will try placing the code in a fresh script, etc... Thanks

Comment: @Jtech this is wrong `Debug.Log(chosenScenario);` change to `Debug.Log("HELLO THERE" +chosenScenario);`

Comment: @Joe Blow Sorry, I thought you meant a screenshot of the console output. I added that at the bottom of the post. Is that not what you were referring to?

Comment: Actually, I just added the case 0 and it's working now. So, now I have cases 0,1,2,3,4,default.

Comment: (The red error is something else) Thank you, but I still don't understand how case 0 addition would make it work...

Comment: Hooray!  Time for martinis.  Your problem was a certain combination of things, not "what you think it was" (if that makes sense).  And I can't be bothered explaining now  :)  Please be sure to read the **four critical suggestions** regarding Debug.Log which I took the time to put in the answer, cheers buddy!  See you on the next question

Comment: There is pretty much never a time where it's appropriate to call somebody "Dude" on this site. Please stop that.

Comment: Dude what's up at autodesk, say hi to Garin for me.  Welcome to SO - don't worry too much about it, language varies all over, it's very friendly in world-English. Anyway, once they sell to google the social engineering is over so it's not worth worrying too much.  Cheers