# What is the meaning of the number in the Unity engine console?

Tags: kinect-sdk, unity-game-engine

[Click here to see the image, Here is the situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTn6o.png)

I am trying to use Debug.Log() to print the length of left arm and right arm in each frame (real time) when I am developing Kinect App. Then I found the numbers inside the red circle are keep increasing. What does it mean? Does it mean the frame number record after I click run App in Unity?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using The String.Split() Function without ignoring duplicates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34711899/using-the-string-split-function-without-ignoring-duplicates)

Answer (score 4):

These number represents the repetition of that Log. You can see that you have pressed the Collapse  tab in Console, So by that, all the same logs will shrink with the number of repetition.

Comment: If possible try not to answer questions that are duplicates .. http://stackoverflow.com/a/34713627/294884  cheers!