# Unity method doesn't work when other script accesses?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have made a multiplayer game in unity, and have a c# script.  It contains a method `public void UpdatePlane` to update the opponents plane.
Inside this method, I want to change a value (`private bool oppdead` to `true`or if just bools do not work for any reason `int opponentisdead`to `1`) or  if I cant change values in there at all even just call the method`makeoppdead()` to change the values there. but exactly those things do not change when they should. I know when inside the method `UpdatePlane`, death becomes true, I receive the Log `("oppplayer dead is true")`but the values doesnt change and the method`makeoppdead()` is not beeing executed, I'm not getting the log`("method was called")` .  Surprisingly for me, on the other hand, it can transform the `opponentPrefab` without any problems. here's the code:

```
        public GameObject opponentPrefab;
        public Rigidbody2D oppPlane;

        private bool _multiplayerReady;
        private string _myParticipantId;


        private bool oppdead;
       int opponentisdead = 0;
    bool boolopponentisdead;

        float opponentdistance;
        float distancex;
        float distancey;
        float distance;

        public void UpdatePlane(string senderId, float x, float y, float z, bool death, float oppdistance)
        {

            MultiplayerController.Instance.GetMyParticipantId();

            opponentdistance = oppdistance;
                if (death)
            {

           //this stuff is NOT being executed:

                makeoppdead();
            opponentisdead = 1;
    boolopponentisdead = true;

    //but I do receive this message:
            Debug.Log("oppplayer dead is true");


            }
           //this stuff is being executed:

                opponentPrefab = GameObject.Find("Opponent");

                opponentPrefab.transform.position = new Vector3(x, y, 0);
                    opponentPrefab.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, z);




        }
        void makeoppdead()
        {
Debug.Log("method was called");
    //do some stuff to provide he is really dead
        }
```

Comment: @sstan please give me a better one and I'll edit immediately

Comment: Please explain in more detail what way it fails. Decribe the behavior of what happens when you *"try to execute another method, or set a bool or an int to another value,"* Also, Unity does allow you to use a a debugger with scripts. Put a breakpoint in and step through the function, see where the logic goes wrong.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain android studio 'attach to proces' recognizes my wifi connected device , but monoDevelop does not. only 'unity editor' to choose. according to http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AttachingMonoDevelopDebuggerToAnAndroidDevice.html

Comment: good grief why did everyone downvote this?

Comment: my first instinct is just that "death" is not true for some reason...

Comment: Can you try to tell us when it does and does not work??

Comment: thank you for those kind words@JoeBlow I'm really sorry if I'm offending someone, I'm trying my best to solve it at my own. Updated my question.

Comment: Maybe try to do the stuff without the `if(death)` for a test and see if it gets executed.

Comment: @GunnarB. tried it, does not work. as I mentioned, `if (dead)` is true when the problem happens

Comment: Can you make the three fields public to check them in the inspector on runtime?

Comment: @GunnarB. Did this. I can change the value to 1 / true and it works perfect. what now?

Comment: You changed them by hand? I meant to just watch them and have a look if  they are really not changing. The only further thing to do I would know right now is to set a breakpoint and debug it.

Comment: I have the problem for debugging , my device is not showing up in monodevelop, look a bit up in these comments @GunnarB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your support, I was able to solve it at my own, with a little different way: it works very well, if I change the value of anything of script 1 in script 2 with                 `(script1).instanceMP.opponentisdead = 1;`